# Hiding "Soft Touch" area in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, touch, hide

Is it possible to remove the Soft Touch area at the bottom of Android Studio's design view? I mean the one that has the TRIANGLE, SQUARE, and CIRCLE shapes?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about emulator in the layout design views navigation bar... If you don't want to see the `navigation bar` simply change the AVD to any `480X800` device configuration.

Comment: No. I was talking about the very designer. That area was blocking some of the components placed on the bottom (I had a Small Text at the bottom of the screen, but the Soft Touch area was overlapping it...)